# ezSQL - Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Tags: php, object, stdclass, ezsql

i create my own function with count of data.

Here is my function.

```
   function  Test($data){
     global $acc;
     $count = $acc->get_var("SELECT Count(*) FROM _users WHERE ID='$data'");
     if($count == 0)
     {
       return true;
     }else{
       return false;
     }
   }
```

But i got This is error : "**PHP Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string**
In This is Line `$count = $acc->get_var("SELECT Count(*) FROM _users WHERE ID='$data'");`
I try var_dump in function and Other ezSQL methods (query,num_rows) but i got every same error.

--
Edit:
Problem solved. I wrong posted $data

Comment: Oh, i found problem. Thank you for the reminder

Comment: You can accept my answer then , and explain what you did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure that

```
$data
```

is not an array

Answer (score 0):

its better practice to pass $acc by reference

```
function  Test($data, &$acc){

     $count = $acc->query("SELECT Count(*) FROM _users WHERE ID='$data'");
     if($count == 0)
     {
       return true;
     }else{
       return false;
     }
```

}